# React, remove value on state, rerenders component

Tags: reactjs

Each time that I add an element to some table, I `set` it's state plus adding another object to the array, which contains a React Component:

```
        setData([
          ...data,
          {
            id: position,
            selector: <DeliverSelector
              key={`selector-${position}`}
              onUpdate={(value) => handleUpdate(value, position)}
            />
          }
        ]);
```

But, when I want to delete an element of the `data` state, I call a function that tries to update the array with the filtered element, but the old `<DeliverSelector` components are getting re-rendered, and they lost the local state that has been set before.

This is the "delete" function:

```
    const delete = (rowToDelete) => setRowToDelete(rowToDelete);

    // with the previous function, it trigger this useEffect:

    useEffect(() => {
        if (rowToDelete) {
          const updatedData = [...myData].filter(
            (data) => data.id !== rowToDelete
          );
          setData(updatedData);
        // some more code...
```

How could avoid getting re-rendered the already rendered `<DeliverSelector>` components? I'm losing their configured local state.

I tried to use a call pack prop like `onUpdate` in order to not use the local state for `<DeliverSelector>` instead, its parent passing as props the value for each selector, but I don't have a way to identify each `<DeliverSelector>`.

Any help, please.

I can show all the code but I think the relevant parts are the shown above (even in a Meet or something)

Comment: *but I don't have a way to identify each `<DeliverSelector>`* What about the ids that you're using to delete?

Comment: Those id represent an entire row, but the value has to be specific for each component on the row. I tried by using hardcoded values but it's not being re-rendered with the new values coming from the parent. I'm doing a codesandbox right now to try to explain.

Comment: Jesus, I have made right now this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ant-design-table-forked-w142y but I thinks it's not the same as my whole situation. But the idea is to show that when I delete some component, the already rendered are getting its initial state

Comment: This codesandbox is better: https://codesandbox.io/s/ant-design-table-forked-1f37b